# lyx to pdf faulty

Tags: lyx

Why did I get this

```
LyX: Cannot view file

File does not exist: C:/Users/tekabu_t/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp5536/lyx_tmpbuf2/newfile1.pdf

OK
```

when run my lyx file?

Can someone help to resolve?

Comment: Can you please post a minimal example .lyx file? Also, you might consider testing LyX 2.2.0rc1, which might have fixed a bug you could be running into. You can download it at ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.2/lyx-2.2.0rc1/